# Change dependencies on NuGet package

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nuget-package, combres

I recently tried to upgrade my log4net to the new 2.0.0 version.
but I wasn't able to do so, cause I have another library (combres.mvc) that has a dependency for log4net 1.2.11

```
Install failed. Rolling back...
Updating 'log4net  1.2.11' to 'log4net 2.0.0' failed. Unable to find a version of 'combres' that is compatible with 'log4net 2.0.0'.
```

Now the combres is an open source which I can download here http://combres.codeplex.com/
Does any one know how can I fix this, that the combres library will support log4net 2.0.0 or any other future version that may come out?

I did tried to contact the publisher with no help, It seems that he is not supporting this library any more...